# Trying to random several links youtube videos in iframe inside div

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

trying to make a iframe with a random youtube links at page upload without any onclick

```js
var glink = 0;
var games = new Array();

games[glink++] = "http://www.youtube.com/pRpvdcjkT3k";
games[glink++] = "http://www.youtube.com/Te4wx4jtiEA";

function randomglink() {
    var random = rand(glink) - 1;
    location.src = games[random];
}
```

```html
<div><iframe width="283" height="242.5" src="randomglink()" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Comment: So? What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this help you :

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <iframe id="ifo" width="283" height="242.5" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
        </div>
        
        <script>
                var glink = 1;
                var games = new Array();

                games[glink++] = "http://www.w3schools.com";
                games[glink++] = "https://mail.google.com";

                function randomglink() {
                     var randomNum =Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1); 
                     document.getElementById("ifo").src = games[randomNum];
                }
            randomglink();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: not working! again.. im trying to send random links to src iframe

Comment: @Tomer Shwartz,please Click on Run code snippet and hide result 3 times ,this code run correctly. and select links as random.

Comment: its working with your links.. but with YouTube links it doesnt working

Comment: @TomerShwartz, use https:// no http:// and Make sure the links are correct.

Comment: hey tnx.. use js file? or?

Comment: @TomerShwartz, use https:// no http:// in your link (youtube) and Make sure the links are correct.

Comment: listen.. if i wrote your code exactly as you wrote.. its work.. but if i wont to use js file in line 8 there is a syntax error

Comment: @TomerShwartz There should be no difference, if you put the JS code between <script></script> tags in a separate .js file. When debugging JS in a browser, always have the Console open (Developer Tools / F12 Tools). There might be error messages that you're missing otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The `src` attribute is *not* like an event (e.g. `onclick` ) that executes a javascript function to get its location/URL. But you can dynamically change the src attribute.

To have a script triggered on page load (without jQuery etc.)

```
<body onload="randomglink()">
```

In order to manipulate your `iframe` element, give it an `id` (has to be unique). In this example I named it `videoFrame`:

```
<div><iframe id="videoFrame" width="283" height="242.5" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Then from your script, set the `src` attribute:

```
function randomglink() {
    var random = rand(glink) - 1;
    document.getElementById('videoFrame').src = games[random];
}
```

Comment: try without success

Comment: im trying local.. didnt upload to the web.. that y your code doesnt working?